# put <something> on, or put on <something>

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, verb-forms, word-order, phrasal-verbs

> Put our bracelet on and don't let those numbers trouble you any more!

Is this correct? I am not sure about using the phrasal verb **put on** together, or separated by a noun :)

And in the second part of sentence, is **those** used correctly?

Comment: Rather more context would help. It sounds to me as if these words could be part of an advertisement of some kind. What are the numbers referred to?

Comment: The numbers refer to mothers that are forced to remember a lot of numbers and hours related to their babies. When have I fed my baby lately? Is he hungry yet? what time did I nurse my baby and what time should I nurse again. Yes, this is advertisement of bracelets that are to remind them to feed their children.

Comment: and even which breast to offer a baby. Its main purpose is getting rid of paper work connected with baby breastfeeding and to keep track of it. Bracelets are simplier solution.

Comment: Referring those bothersome issues *numbers* sounds unnatural to my ears.

Comment: So in your opinion how it should sound?

Answer (score 1):

I won't touch the *numbers* part because the reasons or better call them issues you mention in your comments are not the numbers though most of them are expressed with some numeric values.

Okay, the first part: If you want to put *on* with *put*, go for it, that's okay!

*on* in *put on* serves as an adverbial particle. And, they can **go** between the verb and the object noun. Said that, **Put on our bracelets* is utterly grammatical. I can recall one of the examples from Swan's PEU on this where `Switch off the light` (or similar kind of sentence) was said correct [However, This does not mean that they are always together. Read [some more examples](http://www.englishgrammar.org/adverb-particles-prepositions/) where these particles are *detached* from the verb and placed after the object.

Now the second part.

The pronoun *those* is okay if you have already mentioned what those *numbers are*. In other words, if this is the first sentence of any literature, *those* does not make any sense. You need to mention first what *those* is as a general rule of *pronouns* that replace *nouns*.

Comment: Don't let these/ those issues trouble you!

Comment: Which is correct?

Comment: Both, but in your sentence I'd prefer 'Put on our bracelets' to avoid ambiguity by all means! :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering questions in order:

1. Is [put our bracelet on] correct? Yes, it is valid English.
2. Is [let those numbers] used correctly? Possibly, if the numbers in question are far away from the speaker.

In English, [Demonstratives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative) denote their proximity (closeness) to the speaker. The words *this* and *these* denote they are close (proximal), while the words *that* and *those* denote that they are further away (distal). To illustrate, *these* cups in my hands are much closer than *those* cups on the far end of the table.

Tying that back to the example sentence, the word *those* denotes that the numbers are a distance away from the speaker. Therefore, if the numbers are displayed on a screen across the room, or written on a piece of paper in the next room, the usage would be correct. Even if the numbers in question are a group of rabid living numerals which have been caught and dragged into cages in a different building, the use of *those* would be correct.

If, however, the numbers are displayed on a nearby monitor, or written on the very bracelet being put on which is in the hands of the speaker, the correct word to use would be *these*.